# How to properly select from multiple Redux-slices in mapStateToProps?

Tags: react-native, redux

My Redux store is normalized, i.e. it's quite flat and each entity type has it's own slice.

Here is a simplified example of my Redux store:

```
drawings
  1: {name:'D1', thumbnailId: 33}
  2: {name:'D2', thumbnailId: 34}

thumbnails
  33: {filePath: 'path to local file'}
  34: {filePath: null (i.e. needs to be downloaded)}
```

The listview that shows the drawings whith respective thumbnail needs to be re-rendered when:

- Changes in drawings-slice occurs, i.e. new, removed or updated drawings
- Changes in any of the referenced thumbnails occurs, i.e. thumbnail 34 eventually gets downloaded (download is handled async by a Redux-Saga)

My current **mapStateToProps** is obviously flawed, as it does excessive selections from the Redux store. This happens before the actual view gets hold of its new props, so I cannot control this from `shouldComponentUpdate`.

There are several places in my app where I need a better solution for this.

Here is my flawed mapStateToProps (I'm using Immutable.js):

```
(state, ownProps) => {
  const drawings = selectProjectDrawings(state, ownProps.projectId).map(drawing => {
    const thumbnailFileGuid = drawing.get('thumbnailFileGuid');

    if (!thumbnailFileGuid) return drawing;
    const filePath = selectFile(state, thumbnailFileGuid).get(THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH_FIELD);
    return filePath ? drawing.set('_thumbnailFilePath', filePath) : drawing;
  });

  return {
    drawings: drawings
  };
}
```

> Edit:
>
> A really bad thing with my current solution is that I'm creating new **drawing object** by augmenting them with **_thumbnailPath**. This means that I cannot compare the object references in **shouldComponentUpdate**, as the reference is always altered.
>
> Being able to compare object references is one of the main argument for not mutating the objects, but I have thrown away this opportunity with my flawed solution.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve and what's going wrong. Do you need a list of drawings + thumbnails? Or just a single drawing + thumbnail? What's the expected and actual result of your mapStateToProps?

Comment: mapStateToProps is called whenever the store is updated. My store is updated by a lot of reasons (something synced to/from server by a saga etc). On every store update I'm essentially creating a new list of drawings with attached thumbnails, which forces the drawing list to re-render (if I don't write a very specialised shouldComponentUpdate). I'm thinking that maybe memoizing with Reselect could be a solution, but I'd rather hear how others does this so I can implement a clean concept in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest placing this logic behind a selector. [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a selector memoization library which means that it will do a deep compare of the values for you and if the returned object and all the properties within stay the same, (including deep tree like structures) then it will return the original object.

React then will notice this is the same object instance (not a new one) and not re-render. It is OK if you recreate the drawing object within the selector, since you are not capturing this in any persistent state.

**Side note**: As your app grows, you will notice that all connected components will get `mapStateToProps` called even if it has nothing to do with it, therefore using a memoized selector really helps here. Otherwise your `componentShouldUpdate` gets complex real quick.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented reselect and my crazy logs calmed down due to much less selector calls :)